# High Sierra iconserviceagent goes wild

Tags: finder, external-disk, high-sierra, hfs+

Nearly every time I mount an HFS+ volume on macOS High Sierra 10.13, a process called *iconserviceagent* reads all its files, sometimes hundreds of gigabytes. The system slows down to a crawl and the only solution is to wait or to unmount the disk.

Is this a known issue or bug or something I can configure or just fix straightaway?

Comment: This site may help determine what the problem is: https://gist.github.com/walesmd/7315613

Comment: Thank you, but this didn't help with my problem. However, Apple fixed the issue with the release of macOS 10.13.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has fixed this issue with the release of macOS High Sierra 10.13.2.